# Regex expression for matching folder content

Tags: regex

May be an obvious Regex, but I need to create an expression for filtering the following folders and files

So the regex should match to get the content of the folder
SUNSOLAR_Demo_0/My Documents/CUSTOMER/sale_docs

and exclude the rest.

Eg.:

Include
SUNSOLAR_Demo_0/My Documents/CUSTOMER/sale_docs/invoices/emails/sample.pdf

Exclude:
SUNSOLAR_Demo_0/My Documents/CUSTOMER/unseal/mytest.doc
SUNSOLAR_Demo_0/My Documents/PROVIDERS/orders/invoices.xls

I was trying to do something like, but not luck
"^SUNSOLAR_Demo_0/My Documents/(?!CUSTOMER/sale_docs).*$"

Thanks

Comment: Why use a negative look ahead (`?!`) if you want to match "CUSTOMER/sale_docs" files ? Remove the negative look ahead and it should works fine : `^SUNSOLAR_Demo_0/My Documents/CUSTOMER/sale_docs/.*$`

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `^SUNSOLAR_Demo_0/My Documents/(?!CUSTOMER/sale_docs).*$` matches until `Documents/` and then asserts that what is directly to the right is not `CUSTOMER/sale_docs`

But `CUSTOMER/sale_docs` is actually part of the string that you want to match.

There is no need for a lookaround here.

You can match the whole part of the folder that you want to match, followed by an optional part that starts with `/` and the rest of the line.

```
^SUNSOLAR_Demo_0/My Documents/CUSTOMER/sale_docs(?:/.*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3qlmCL/1)